# Build UserControl to display both text and image dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, desktop-application

I am building a quiz redistributable desktop application. Questions can be text or image or both. 
Someone suggested i build a text and  image dynamic user control to display the questions. I have searched all round but cant find any tutorial that shows how to build such user control.

i was reffered to http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html, 
http://en.csharp-online.net/Create_List_Controls,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx
but it dosent help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you need some control that can display a dynamic content (text/image). I can suggest you to  use the content control that selects its content DataTemplate according to it's current data context. 
I'will put a whole solution in several minutes.

```
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentControlContent.Content}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soSandBoxListView:SingleTextModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SingleModelContent}" Background="Tan"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soSandBoxListView:MultipleTextModel}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Background="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Background="Red"></TextBlock>
                        <!--use the binding to your picture presentation in model-->
                        <Image Source="Resources/yotveta.jpg" Stretch="None"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sir. Can this be done using Windows forms?

Comment: @OkwuPrecious Hi, I sure that there is an ability to do this in a winforms, but I can't help you with this. Sorry ;).